# How to handle message conversation participant IDs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, messaging

I am creating my own Rails messaging system from scratch, using Facebook & SMS one-conversation-per-two-people type as a role model. I've researched and planned it for a few hours now, and decided I will have a `Conversation` model along with `Message` model. Messages will belong to Conversation and hold the content. Conversation model will be used finding the conversation between these two people.

Here's what my Conversation model currently looks like in migration:

```
    create_table :conversations do |t|
      t.integer :participant_id
      t.integer :initiator_id

      t.timestamps
    end
```

However, with this, when finding conversations, I will have to search `current_user.id` in both `participant_id` and `initiator_id` columns! That doesn't feel to me a good practice at all. Another idea I had is to store both in an array of two and find if current_user.id exists in that.

**(TL;DR) My question:** Is it more efficient to store users participating in the conversation like this or in an array? Or is there a third, most efficient way?

Thank you in advance, all answers are gigantically appreciated!

Comment: I think the way you have it, is pretty efficient. If you think about it from a DB query perspective, it's just
SELECT * FROMconversations WHERE user.participant_id =  X OR user.initiator_id = X